# How to make the median of an inner calculated table MySQL?

Tags: mysql, median

I want to make the median of a data difference table like the following:

```
18
23
23
28
21
```

I did it with:

```
SELECT
-- Difference between the date the check was recorded in the database and the date of the pledge 
DATEDIFF(`orders`.`created_at`, `o_creation`.`created_at`) 
-- To find the date of creation of the donation, a join is made between honored by and initial Order ID 
from `orders`
left join `orders` AS `o_creation`
    on `o_creation`.`promise_honored_by_id` = `orders`.`order_id`
-- Only checks received (not promises created) and validated are kept
WHERE (`orders`.`mean` = 'Chèque' AND 
    `orders`.`promise_honored_by_id` is NULL AND
    `orders`.`status` = 2)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SET @rowindex := -1;
 
SELECT
   AVG(g)
FROM
   (SELECT @rowindex:=@rowindex + 1 AS rowindex
           
    FROM(
        SELECT
            -- Difference entre la date d'enregistrement du chèque dans la BDD et la date de promesse de don 
            DATEDIFF(`orders`.`created_at`, `o_creation`.`created_at`) 
        -- Pour trouver la date de création du don on fait la jointure entre honored by et Order ID initial 
        from `orders`
        left join `orders` AS `o_creation`
            on `o_creation`.`promise_honored_by_id` = `orders`.`order_id`
        -- On garde que les chèques reçus (et non les promesses créées) et validés
        WHERE (`orders`.`mean` = 'Chèque' AND 
            `orders`.`promise_honored_by_id` is NULL AND
            `orders`.`status` = 2)
    )  AS `difference`
    ORDER BY `difference`) AS g
WHERE
    g.rowindex IN (FLOOR(@rowindex / 2) , CEIL(@rowindex / 2));
```

But it retursn me an error:

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AVG(g) FROM (SELECT @rowindex:=@rowindex + 1 AS rowindex, ' at line 44*

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` needs the name of a column - not the name of a table. `g` is a table.

Comment: Damn ! Thanks for the insight. SO I need to use `difference` alias?

Comment: You will have to expose `difference` to the outer query - otherwise it is not visible.